# Where can I download a pre-compiled version of WinJS?

Tags: winjs

I am unable to find a pre-compiled version of WinJS to download. I just want a .zip with a CSS and JS file.

I can find [the source at Github](https://github.com/winjs/winjs) but I'm unable to compile it on my Surface RT so I really need a pre-compiled version.

Anyone know where it is available for download, pre-compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Microsoft has made a lot of progress and has now gotten on board with how libraries are normally deployed.  You can get it from NPM, Bower, CDN, or create a custom build.  Details at http://try.buildwinjs.com/#get

---

**Original answer:**

If you install Visual Studio 2013 (you'll need a x86 or x64 PC, not your Surface RT) it will be there.  The stuff on GitHub is really not ready for use yet.  They promised to publish the files on a CDN when it is.  But for now, there are still a ton of bugs that limit it's usefulness outside Windows/WP apps (as you can also see on GitHub) so publishing a compiled build would be counterproductive.

That said... if you look at http://try.buildwinjs.com, you can steal the compiled build it uses :)

- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/base.min.js?v1.0.84
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/ui.min.js?v1.0.84
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/en-us/base.strings.js?v1.0.84
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/en-us/ui.strings.js?v1.0.84
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/css/ui-dark.css?v1.0.84
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/css/ui-light.css?v1.0.84

Comment: Please don't feed help vampires.

Comment: It's a legit question... How often does MSFT release a library only in source form?  They did with winjs so people are confused

Comment: It's now possible to download a compiled version at http://try.buildwinjs.com/#get